# relative path SQLite3 connection with PDO not working

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have a Class function in PHP (**GetMenuItems.php**) that connects to the DB and gets the menu items. This function is called from the **Menu.php** and **MenuAdmin.php** files.

The problem is, it works fine on **Menu.php** and not in **MenuAdmin.php**.

Folder structure:

- localhost

  - FundosDB.db
  - index.php
  - Menu.php
  - Class

    - GetMenuItems.php
  - Admin

    - Admin.php
    - MenuAdmin.php

**Connection:**
`$db = new PDO('sqlite:FundosDB.db');`

If I change the connection to: `$db = new PDO('sqlite:..\FundosDB.db');` the opposite happens.

How can I make it work for both situations? And, the relative path shouldn't be between the class file where the connection is made and the DB file instead of between the file that calls the function in the class and the DB file? I am confused.

Comment: Use `SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: How do you use the **GetMenuItems.php** in both the files?

Comment: Yes, that works. ;) What about the last question? Thank you very much.

Comment: @codisfy, with `require_once("Class\GetMenuItems.php");` or `require_once("..\Class\GetMenuItems.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a path to your db file using absolute path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, something like:

```
define('DB_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/FundosDB.db');
```

Then use it everywhere:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:' . DB_PATH);
```